# Using one tap on the screen to make object go up on touchesBegan variable?

Tags: objective-c

I have a code where you have to tap and hold to keep your object flying up in the air.  If you release your finger from the screen (the tap ends0, the object goes down.  How do I edit the code so that I just tap the screen once to make the object go up instead of tap and then leaving the tap in place?

The code that involves tap and hold:

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  if (Start == YES) {

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(HeliMove) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    Start = NO;

    }

Y = -7;
Heli.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HeliUp.png"];

}

 -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

Y = 7;
Heli.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HeliDown.png"];

 }

 -(void)HeliMove{

Heli.center = CGPointMake(Heli.center.x, Heli.center.y + Y);

 }
```

The code I have (different game) where I can tap only once to make the object go up:

```
 #pragma mark touch
 -(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
if(!m_bGameIsPlaying || m_bGameExit || m_bConflictWithBird || boostFlag)
    return;

touchDelayTime = 0;
touchBeginTime = [event timestamp];
float delay;
if(m_rPillarVx == 0){
    smoothSpeed = INIT_SMOOTH_SPEED;
    smoothTotalDis = 80;
    delay = 0.13;
}else{
    smoothSpeed = INIT_SMOOTH_SPEED;
    smoothTotalDis = 50;
    delay = 0.23;
}
if(g_fIsIPad)
    smoothSpeed *= 2;

if(m_rPillarVx == 0){

    for(Bird *Bird in arrBirds)
    {
        if(Bird != nil && Bird.ccNode !=nil){
            [Bird setActive:TRUE];
            if(g_specGameItem != ITEM_SPIKE)
                [Bird setCollisionMaskBits:0x0002];
        }
    }

    for(Coin *coin in arrCoins)
    {
        if(coin != nil && coin.ccNode != nil){
            [coin setActive:TRUE];
            [coin setCollisionMaskBits:0x0002];
        }
    }

    for(GameSpecItem *specItem in arrSpecItems)
    {
        if(specItem != nil && specItem.ccNode != nil)
        {
            [specItem setActive:TRUE];
            [specItem setCollisionMaskBits:0x0002];
        }
    }
}

int faster = [AppSettings speedLevel];
 m_rPillarVx = INIT_PILLAR_SPEED*g_fx*powf(1.05, m_nLevel) * (1 + 0.1 * faster);

if(g_specGameItem == ITEM_ROCKET)
{
    [self unschedule:@selector(rocketMoveOfCharacter)];
    [self schedule:@selector(rocketMoveOfCharacter) interval:0.01];
    [myself addFireEmitter];
    return;
}

[myself jump];
[self setStamina];
[self unschedule:@selector(startSmoothlyMove)];
[self schedule:@selector(startSmoothlyMove) interval:delay];

 }

 - (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
 {
if(g_specGameItem == ITEM_ROCKET){
    [self unschedule:@selector(rocketMoveOfCharacter)];
    //Shen
    if(myself != nil)
        [myself deleteFireEmitter];
 //        if(g_fIsIPad)
 //            [myself setLinearVelocity:b2Vec2(0.0f, -12.0f)];
 //        else
 //            [myself setLinearVelocity:b2Vec2(0.0f, -6.0f)];
  //        return;
}

touchDelayTime = [event timestamp] - touchBeginTime;
[self unschedule:@selector(smoothlyMoveOfCharacter)];
smoothMovedDis = 0;
 }
```

Comment: Smells like another Flappy Bird clone is in the works ;)

Comment: @ChrisWagner You caught me! I actually have two games.  One is being reskinned and the other needs more polishing.  The one that is being reskinned....I'm trying to figure out how to replicate the code into my other game.  It has elements I want to add.  It will be similar to Flappy Bird, but I hope it will be better.  Clones are great, but not really original.  First, I need someone to help me with this code question first ;)